# RavenDB 2.5 Patch unique data to each document

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm using RavenDB 2.5. I want to update a single field on all documents in a specific collection. I want each document to have a unique value in this field. I am currently attempting this via 'patching' from the web portal, but I will gladly do it another way if that is needed.

Here is what I tried in the patch request in the web portal.

```
var i = 1000;
this.UniqueField = i++;
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Every field gets a value of 1000. I don't know what else to try though.

Secondarily, I would prefer the unique values to be a Guid (cast to a string) instead of an integer. However, I will take whatever I can get as long as the fields are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jscript to define a guid and then assign a new one to each field:

Suppose you wanted to set`UniqueField` on each User object (remember to Patch Collection)

[image]

Guid code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the link on the Guid code, too.